# What is meant by 'interdiscursivity' in discursive practice by Fairclough?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, language, critical-theory

I am conducting a Critical Discourse Analysis on Chinese newspapers, such as the Global Times, to investigate how ethnicity became a securitized threat in the media.
However, Fairclough's second dimension has stumped me.
I understand how to look out for Intertextuality with the overt use of direct or indirect quotations etc, however the Interdiscursivity section is lost on me!
From what I can make out, it discusses how different genres and discourse are drawn upon. But what is meant by 'genre' in this sense? What am I supposed to be looking out for?

Comment: See [Interdiscourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdiscourse) : "the utterance is the natural meaningful unit of speech, which others are supposed to respond to, that is, others interpret the utterance by situating it in a discursive context. But, an utterance may be interpreted (contextualised) in various ways, and interdiscourse and interdiscursivity denote how certain such interpretations (and relations to other discourses) are socially more privileged than others.  1/2

Comment: Since interdiscourse privileges certain interpretations, it has a close affinity to the concepts of ideology, hegemony and power (sociology). Therefore, the embedding of a discourse in an interdiscourse is an ideological interpretation of the discourse." 2/2

Comment: In a nutshell, a "unit of speech": statement, political discourse, text has not a fixed and "universal" meaning (like in mathematics and logic) but it is interpreted by the listener/reader according to a context: culture, society, ideology, etc.

Comment: "Genre" here is (IMO) [Literary genre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_genre): is a category of literary composition. Genres may be determined by literary technique, tone, content, or even (as in the case of fiction) length.

Comment: It's worth noting that the way discourse is being used in interdiscursivity, has a lot do with Foucault. His picture of 'discursive formations' can be a whole discipline like say 'natural history', with it's own culture of discourse; rather than necessarily it being an ideology, or merely a genre. There have been racist and xenophobic discourses happening forever, which can be easily tapped in to, and who's audience will recognise special phrasings and 'dog whistles' from. Haidt in his moral foundations theory notes a greater conservative focus on purity/sanctity, & language about cleanliness

Answer (score 0):

According to reference [here](https://ses.library.usyd.edu.au/bitstream/handle/2123/1701/05chapter4.pdf;jsessionid=77E3D11D74D99E75956623BBD90E25F9?sequence=5):

> The key term is genre, which, for Fairclough, is “the use of language associated with a
> particular social activity” (Fairclough, 1993, p. 138). For him, “different genres are different means of production of a specifically textual sort, different resources for
> texturing” (Fairclough, 2000, p.441). Genre is also a means of textual structuring and
> a set of relatively stable conventions, which are both creative and conservative. That
> means that genre is both relatively stable and at the same time open to change.

> Critical discourse analysis considers the relationship between language use and wider
> social and cultural structures. In Fairclough’s term this means the relationships
> between a specific communicative event, such as newspaper coverage of an event,
> and the total structure of an order of discourse, as well as modifications to the order of
> discourse and its constituents, genres and discourses (Fairclough, 1995a).

> For the operationalization of these theoretical considerations Fairclough develops an
> analytical framework (Fairclough, 1992a, 1995a), drawing on the concepts of
> intertextuality (that is the relationship between texts ‘before’ and ‘after’),
> interdiscursivity (that is the combination of genres and discourses in a text) and
> hegemony (the predominance in and the dominance of political, ideological and
> cultural domains of a society) (Fairclough, 1995a). He attributes these three
> dimensions to each discursive event. According to Fairclough, a discursive event is
> simultaneously text, discursive practice (including the production and interpretation of
> texts) and social practice.

There're 2 other notes and powerpoint I found [here](https://ocw.nagoya-u.jp/files/75/notes_chap4.pdf) and [here](http://file.upi.edu/Direktori/FPBS/JUR._PEND._BHS._DAN_SASTRA_INDONESIA/194103191965031-YOYO_MULYANA/GENRE_AND_DISCOURSE.pdf), hope it'll be helpful...